# Problems using cubeSQL trying to add data to table

Tags: sql

I just got cubeSQL admin and SQL Lite manager, and am new at this, trying to create a database for an mobile app to get video info and urls from to stream. I set up a database and connected it to the manager, but cannot get it to accept the script that I am using. This is what i am putting in to get it to add data to a table.

```sql
INSERT INTO Sabbath School
VALUES
(number 1, hello, great, google.com, google.com),
```

This is the error I get:
[image]

Here are screenshots of what I am working with. The first one is the database:
[image: database screenshot]

The next one is the table configuration
[image]

The final one is what the table looks like.
[image]

Any help would be most appreciated as to what I am doing wrong here. I am really not knowing what I am doing and trying to learn how to use sql.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a "quoted identifier" issue.  Since the table name has a space in it, you will need to surround the table in double quotes.  The query parser believes your table name is "Sabbath" and is expecting the VALUES keyword next, or an opening parenthesis `(` to start your `(column list)`.  Since it sees "School" next, you get the syntax error.  My preference is to avoid spaces in table names so you don't need to quote it all the time.